# dateTime string format (2021-09-18T09:00) being changed to 2021-09-18 09:00 when filing to sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

The sheet originally stored date-time strings in ISO-8601 ("T"<hh:mm>, i.e. "2021-06-30T21:00"). For some reason, upon trying to file these date-times as a string, the format of the date-time in the cell is being applied to " "<hh:mm> (ISO-8601 without the "T"). I added a logger.log just prior to the filing and I can see that the "T" is still in the string. Any ideas?

Note that the code hasn't changed in 2 months and this started happening 2 weeks ago. Thinking something has changed with google sheets auto-correcting date-time strings

```
Logger.log(data);

sheet.setActiveRange(range).setValues(data);

var LastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
```

Log "data":

```
[10.0, 29, 6.0, 2021-09-17T21:00, 2021-09-18T09:00, Yes, , 209, mail@mail.com, Sun Aug 15 2021 23:35:45 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time), Yes, , , , ]]"
```

How it's displaying in the sheet (note the date format in piece 3 and 4 is changed in the sheet)

```
10 29 6 2021-09-17 21:00 2021-09-18 9:00 Yes 209 mail@mail.com Sun Aug 15 2021 23:35:45 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) Yes
```

I tried something like below and it seemed to have no affect.

```
sheet.getRangeList(["D2:D"+LastRow]).setNumberFormat('@STRING@');
```

Comment: I am also facing this issue since last 1 week - Appsscript has changed something internally without any notification, my code which was working for the last 3years has stopped working

Comment: @DarpanSanghavi, see my solution below. It might fix your issue too.

Comment: Any idea why this is a problem all of a sudden?  My code hasn't changed in a few months and it came up in the last 2 weeks.  I definitely think setting the number format prior is the solution here though.

Comment: That I'm not sure. Most likely, if it works until some time then it doesn't, then something changed at the background. I can't find any documentations regarding this changes though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that formatting the value after it was written especially on strings like this will not likely fix the issue.

You need to format the cells right before they are written.

#### Sample code:

```
function myFunction() {
  data = [[10.0, 29, 6.0, "2021-09-17T21:00", "2021-09-18T09:00", "Yes", , 209, "mail@mail.com", "Sun Aug 15 2021 23:35:45 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)", "Yes", , , , ]];
  
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  // set range D2:E to string before applying data
  sheet.getRange(2, 4, lastRow + 1, 2).setNumberFormat('@STRING@');
  // write data 
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
  // in your case, applying string format after will not fix the data written before 
}
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks, this worked for the most part, but wouldn't if the number format was applied before appending a new row.    The below solution (although not ideal, seems like more of a workaround), seemed to work in all cases.
  sheet.getRangeList(["L2:M"+calLastRow]).setNumberFormat("yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm");
sheet.getRangeList(["L2:M"+calLastRow]).setNumberFormat('@STRING@');

Comment: For example, the first snippet below works, while the second doesn't.         
 
 Works:
 sheet.getRangeList(["B2:E"+(LastRow+1),"H2:H"+(LastRow+1),"J2:J"+(LastRow+1)]).setNumberFormat('@STRING@');
  sheet.setActiveRange(range).setValues(data);
 
 Doesn't work:
 sheet.getRangeList(["L2:M"+(sheet.getLastRow()+1)]).setNumberFormat('@STRING@');
  sheet.appendRow([data]);
 
 Fix for second:
 sheet.appendRow([data]);
 sheet.getRangeList(["L2:M"+calLastRow]).setNumberFormat("yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm");
  sheet.getRangeList(["L2:M"+calLastRow]).setNumberFormat('@STRING@');

Comment: As long as you format the cell before you add the data. and if you add a row, make sure to format after adding the row. `add row -> format -> write`. You were writing on a cell that isnt formatted because using `appendRow` will insert a row using default formatting. If you want to write into the new row appended, then format it before writing.

Comment: @RyanHunter, If this answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 1):

`2021-09-18 09:00` is the default display format for `datetime` in your spreadsheet.

The type is `time` but not `string` such that you should format it with something like `M-D H:m`.

Comment: Thank you @idfurw.  Is this something that changed recently?  How would I go about forcing the Y-M-D"T"H:m format to be the default time format in my sheet.  Is it done via google sheets settings or is it done per cell at runtime?  This datetime has always been passed to the sheet as a string, and it previously treated it as one.